# Inserting dynamic data into Google Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have task to insert dynamic data to `Google PieChart`.

[Playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#pie_chart)

In that link I insert this code:

```
function drawVisualization() {
// Create and populate the data table.
var data = google.visualization.DataTable();

var mycars=["Saab","Volvo","BMW"];
var mypoints=[4,12,45];

data.addColumn('string', 'Cars');
data.addColumn('number', 'Numbers'); 
data.addRows(mycars.length);
for  (var i = 0; i < mycars.length; i++){
  data.setCell(i,0,mycars[i]);
  data.setCell(i,1,mypoints[i]);
}
// Create and draw the visualization.
new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
draw(data, {title:"So, how was your day?"});
}
```

​

In the following example I get dynamic arrays `mycars` and `mypoints`, then I try to insert those arrays to chart within `for loop`.

PieChart isn't displaying. What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 3):

You have a javascript error.  You need to use the `new` keyword when instantiating the DataTable.

Replace

```
var data = google.visualization.DataTable();
```

with

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem using code in jquery like this :

```
$("#piechart_3d").show();
google.load("visualization", "1", {
    packages: ["corechart"], callback: function () {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                        ['Going', 'a Day'],
                        ['Car', 11],
                        ['Bus', 2],
                        ['Moto', 2]
                    ]);
        var options = {
                        title: 'Report',
                        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                        is3D: true,
                    };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
});
```